# Heroku 'Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch'

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I've been trying to deploy using Heroku, however every time I try I get the error message
'Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch'

I've tried everything, including localhost to '0.0.0.0' and process.env.PORT. What's going wrong?

Here's a very simple code sample I've been testing with:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ hi: 'there' });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0');
```

As well, just in case, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines":{
       "node":"12.16.2",
       "npm":"6.14.4"
 },
  "scripts": {
       "start":"node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^6.14.4"
  }
}
```

Here's the Heroku log:

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9p15.png)

Comment: Are you committing to the master git branch? Is the first code block you provided the content of `index.js` or some other file?